# Why can't I update the aspectRatio within the chartjs chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

If I try to change the aspectRatio of the chart, then I can't do that. This page also indicates that it should be possible. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

What I've tried is to see in this pen. https://codepen.io/snowflakemelter/pen/WNNKKvG

javascript, css, html. In this order you will find the code below.

```js
//works not
function setAspectRatio(){
  myChart.options.aspectRatio = 2;
  myChart.update();
}
setAspectRatio()

//works
function setChartLabels(){
  myChart.data.datasets[0].label = "whatEver";
  myChart.update();
}
setChartLabels()
```

```css
.box{
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.2/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>

  <div class="box">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: [ 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
 
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          aspectRatio: 1,
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please help, someone.. :p

Comment: Try doing a `myChart.destroy();` then re-initializing the chart in your `setAspectRatio()`. That `.update()` method never seems to work for me. Sample: https://codepen.io/iskandarreza/pen/xxxJmQO

Comment: You are a god. That's clever! Can I also specify the aspectRatio before the chart is created at all or as some sort of callback? I'm going to take another good look at this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6271) in Chart.js about changes on `chart.options.aspectRatio` not taken into account. As a workaround, you can edit `chart.aspectRatio` directly and then call `chart.resize()`.

```js
function setAspectRatio() {
    myChart.aspectRatio = 9;
    myChart.resize();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a new programmer. Shall I delete this stackoverflow page?

Comment: No ;), just approve my answer as it could help some other people.